# Proof-irrelevance of identity types

Tags: logic, homotopy-theory, type-theory, lambda-calculus, constructive-mathematics

In constructive type theories, we make a distinction between extensional and intensional identity types. It's trivial that extensional identity types are *proof-irrelevant* as the inhabitant of an extensional identity type is a constant $\textsf{eq}:\textsf{Eq}(a,b,A)$ (for $a,b:A$ and $a=b:A$). Regarding intensional identity types, I have two questions:

1. Let $A$ be an arbitrary type, is the intensional identity type $\textsf{Id}(a,b,A)$ (for $a,b:A$ and $a=b:A$) proof-irrelevant?
2. Let $A$ be a proof-irrelevant type, is $\textsf{Id}(a,b,A)$ (for $a,b:A$ and $a=b:A$) proof-irrelevant?

Note: A type $A$ is said to be proof-irrelevant iff $A$ satisfies: $(\Pi x,y:A)\textsf{Id}(x,y,A)$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not writing this as an answer because I don't have references, but the answer to 1. is no in general (e.g. in HoTT, $a=_A b$ need not be contractible, e.g. $p=_{S^1} p$ is essentially $\Omega(S^1,p) \simeq \mathbb Z$). The answer to 2. should be yes, but I'm not sure (again, I'm thinking about HoTT, and the homotopical interpretation : if $A$ is contractible, so is $\Omega A$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Let  be an arbitrary type, is the intensional identity type
> (,,) (for ,: and =:) proof-irrelevant?

This is not provable or disprovable in intensional type theory. You can add it as an axiom (uniqueness of identity proofs, UIP), or add axioms which imply its negation. Extensional type theory does the former, homotopy type theory the latter. The univalence axiom in HoTT implies the negation of UIP.

> Let  be a proof-irrelevant type, is (,,) (for ,:
> and =:) proof-irrelevant?

Yes. See Lemma 3.3.4 in the [HoTT book](https://hott.github.io/book/nightly/hott-online-1267-g7fa5cd9.pdf), or Chapter 7 for a more general treatment.

In general, types have h-levels, which measures the amount of relevant information in identity types. Level $0$ has types which are equivalent to the unit type, and level $(n+1)$ has types whose identity types are at level n. In the book, levels start from $-2$ for historical reasons, but sometimes people start from $0$. If a type is at level $n$, it is also at level $(n + 1)$, hence its identity type is also at level $n$. Since being at level $1$ is the same as being proof-irrelevant, a proof-irrelevant type has proof-irrelevant identity types.

These results about h-levels hold in plain intensional type theory, with no HoTT-specific features required.

Comment: While this answer is okay, I’d like to point out that “proof-irrelevant” doesn’t mean “computation-irrelevant” or “erasable”.  See, for example, [this infamous infelicity](https://homotopytypetheory.org/2013/10/28/the-truncation-map-_-%e2%84%95-%e2%80%96%e2%84%95%e2%80%96-is-nearly-invertible/).